# Three.js game turbulent 'WASD' movement and collideable mesh-events issue

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl

Hey this is a 'game' I'm working on: http://goo.gl/2rkQgj

it is very unpolished.
here is the index.html
:http://pastebin.com/BstF7K4w

I had general questions about why when you 'strafe' the movement gets so turbulent in the chase camera position?

How do i change the chase camera to be smoother?
How do I make my mesh not do that, stop on a dime thing and add some drift?
How do i push more meshes to the collideable mesh list, I've tried the other meshes and it wont run.

I want things to happen when it hits a red mesh and also i can't add move functions to the red meshes like

"wall.rotation.y += 2;"  won't run.

Also how do i change the background color of the top print out area?  The div bg color wasn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So check it out. Rather than updating the position of the camera you can simply add the camera to the player model after it loads.

```
 //scene.add(camera)
 playerModel.add(camera)
```

Now the camera position will be relative to the player model so you might want to pull the camera back a little bit to position it behind the player.

```
camera.position.z = -100
```

Now updating the payer's position and rotation will also adjust the camera's position and rotation!

*This answer is not intended to be copied and pasted so you'll have adapt it to your code but it should work. Your question regarding drifting player movement will require significant rewriting. Make another post and I'll try to help!*

Comment: hmm tried, somethings, got some interesting results, i tried this with my chase and top camera.  pressing '1' and '2', gives you two different cameras, maybe that is complicating the issue, anyway, thanks for replying.  By significant re-writing do you mean to my code or my question?  Basically if you http://goo.gl/2rkQgj try to strafe or move in two directions at once, or even one it kind of ...doesn't move smoothly, there's a lot of shaking, the topcamera doesn't show this though, so it's definitely how i'm attaching the camera to my mesh.

Comment: What I mean is that that easing character movement is kind of a rabbit hole. It deserves it's own post. Your link is expired update it and I'll check it out?

Comment: It looks like your player model is getting ahead of the camera and you're calling camera.lookAt() to look at the player and then they realign on the next draw where you again call camera.lookAy(). Thats what causes the jump.

Comment: http://shawnwhinnery.com/HTMLZ/games/alpha_10/ this is an OLD version of the game I'm working on :)

Comment: nice, I like that motion a lot, I really like the 3D word and visualization of the contact sphere mesh. and I call camera.lookAt(mesh.position) twice?  or is it that it's in some loop?  It's in the code only once after the offset is made, I don't understand.  Maybe I need to start a new three.js project, thanks man I appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem. If you add the camera to the player the camera will be in the player's belly so you want to pull it back a little (something like 'camera.position.z = -100') and then run camera.lookAt(mesh.position) once. It will point the camera at the player and then you shouldn't have to call camera.lookAt() again. Good luck. I'm at shawnsdrive@gmail.com hit me up if you need more help!